# Can we omit the 吗 at the end of a 难道 rhetorical question?

Tags: grammar, particles

The [Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Rhetorical_questions_with_%22nandao%22) writes:

> Note that 难道 can only be used for rhetorical questions which could be answered with yes or no, and generally end with 吗.

And gives examples such as:

> 今天是我的生日，**难道**你不知道**吗**？

However, none of the examples on 标准教程HSK4上 page 105 include 吗, such as:

> 怎么有买了这么多饼干和巧克力？**难道**你不减肥了？

From the examples I've seen, I'm getting the impression that the 吗 at the end can be included or omitted without changing the meaning.

**Question**: Can we omit the 吗 at the end of a 难道 rhetorical question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, definitely you can. However, in some situations, with 吗 it sounds more natural and less rude. And sometimes, with 吗 it might sound less criticizing, such as your first example 今天是我的生日，难道你不知道吗?

Answer (score 1):

"今天是我的生日，**难道**你不知道吗？" (Today is my birthday, **could it be** you don't know that?) is a rhetorical question

Omitting "吗" and write "今天是我的生日，难道你不知道？" or "难道你不知道今天是我的生日?" is still perfectly acceptable as a rhetorical question, as long as there's a question mark at the end.

Even without "难道" , "今天是我的生日，你不知道吗？" can still be a rhetorical question if you are expected to know. And you are expected to answer "of course I know"

If you are not expected to know, then it is a real question.  I really am asking "is it true that you don't know?" and your answer can be "yes, I know" or "no, I don't"